# Text is cropped at the top with certain fonts in Pygame

Tags: fonts, pygame

I'm working on a Pokémon-style dialog box in Pygame. I'm using the [Pokemon GB](http://www.fontspace.com/jackster-productions/pokemon-gb) font, but for some reason the text is cropped at the top. It looks like `pygame.font.Font.size` doesn't calculate properly the `Surface` size needed to render the text.
[image]

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niiJ3.png) shows what it's supposed to look like.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 192))
window.fill((255, 255, 255))

POKEFONT = pygame.font.Font("Pokemon GB.ttf", 32)
positions = [[32, 64], [36, 128]]
lines = ["Hello there!", "Welcome to the"]

for line, pos in zip(lines, positions):
    text = POKEFONT.render(line, True, (0, 0, 0))
    rect = text.get_rect()
    rect.topleft = pos
    window.blit(text, rect)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

The [PKMN RBYGSC](http://www.dafont.com/fr/pkmn-rbygsc.font) font looks nearly identical but renders properly. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `pygame.freetype` which is available as of Pygame 1.9.2.

[image]

PKMN RBYGSC is on the left and Pokemon GB on the right. The exclamation mark crosses both the max ascent line and the baseline in Pokemon GB (see [this page](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Using_the_Fontforge_Drawing_Tools.html#mastering-fontforges-drawing-tools) for terminology). It looks like `pygame.font` ignores anything outside those lines but `pygame.freetype` doesn't.

This modified version of the code gives the right result:
[image]

```py
import pygame.freetype 

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 192))
window.fill((255, 255, 255))

POKEFONT = pygame.freetype.Font("Pokemon GB.ttf", 32)
positions = [[32, 64], [36, 128]]
lines = ["Hello there!", "Welcome to the"]

for line, pos in zip(lines, positions):
    text, rect = POKEFONT.render(line, (0, 0, 0))
    rect.topleft = pos
    window.blit(text, rect)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```